# Euclidean Distance between 2 Vectors Implementation

Tags: java, arrays, vector, euclidean-distance

I working through a few exercises from an academic programing book. The task is to implement 2 vectors and calculate the Euclidean distance between thereof. No this is not Home Work, rather self studying.

I'm seeking some feedback on the correctness of my distance implementation.

```
public class EuclideanDist
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   
        EuclideanDist euc = new EuclideanDist();
        Random rnd = new Random();        

        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        double[] a = new double[N];
        double[] b = new double[N];
        double[] x = new double[N];

        euc.print(euc.init(a, rnd));        
        euc.print(euc.init(b, rnd));        
        print(euc.distance(a, b, x));
    }

    private double[] init(double[] src, Random rnd)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < src.length; i++)
        {
            src[i] = rnd.nextDouble();
        }
        return src;
    }
    private double[] distance(double[] a, double[] b, double[] x)
    {
        double diff; 
        int N = a.length;

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            diff = a[i] - b[i];
            x[i] = Math.sqrt(diff * diff);
        }
        return x;
    }
    private static void print(double[] x)
    {
        int N = x.length;
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            System.out.print(" " + x[j] + " ");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: what issue do you have?

Comment: This is Java; why did you tag it C++?

Comment: Distance should be a scalar, not a vector; the square root of the sum of the squares of the distances along each axis. `sqrt(diff * diff)` is obviously just `diff`.

Comment: I think OP is using `sqrt(diff*diff)` instead of `abs` to ensure `diff` is +ve.  Not commenting on the optimality or otherwise, but `sqrt(diff*diff)` is not always equal to `diff`

Comment: OP - I think you have a conceptual problem, rather than a programming one.  Try reading [some resources](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) on what Euclidian distance means - your implementation and the comment on the answer imply that you have misunderstood.

Comment: @JRichardSnape thanks for the feedback I will do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on the suggestions of @AlanStokes, the following codes seems to be one solution (I have tested it):

```
import java.util.Random;

public class EuclideanDist {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EuclideanDist euc = new EuclideanDist();
        Random rnd = new Random();

        int N = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        double[] a = new double[N];
        double[] b = new double[N];

        euc.print(euc.init(a, rnd));
        euc.print(euc.init(b, rnd));
        System.out.println(euc.distance(a, b));
    }

    private double[] init(double[] src, Random rnd) {
        for (int i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
            src[i] = rnd.nextDouble();
        }
        return src;
    }

    private double distance(double[] a, double[] b) {
        double diff_square_sum = 0.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            diff_square_sum += (a[i] - b[i]) * (a[i] - b[i]);
        }
        return Math.sqrt(diff_square_sum);
    }

    private void print(double[] x) {
        for (int j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {
            System.out.print(" " + x[j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems your solution gives an aggregate distance. In the case where I would like to determine the distance between entries of the arrays it doesn't seem this solution would work. Your feedback is totally welcomed..

Comment: My thought is close to @JRichardSnape; or, could you kindly provide the mathematical formula about the distance you would like to compute?

Comment: @d_blk Thanks a lot!